# Ember-cli-rails No route match for ember's paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-cli, ember-cli-rails

In a Rails and Ember project, I decided to use [EmberCLI Rails](https://github.com/rwz/ember-cli-rails) because I want to do integration tests with Capybara and all my favorite testing gems.

I installed it and it works when I go to the home page.

I added routes on ember like this :

```
  import Ember from 'ember'
  import config from './config/environment'

  Router = Ember.Router.extend(location: config.locationType)
  Router.map ->
    @resource 'users'

  export default Router
```

When I go on `http://localhost:3000/users`, I have a no route matches error. I understand why this is happening, Rails does not load routes of embers. Is there a solution to do it or is it just impossible with EmberCli-Rails for now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Rails app needs a wildcard route so it knows to handle those requests through your Ember app controller. Can you try adding a route in `routes.rb`:

```
get '/:all', to: "ember#index"
```

substituting `ember#index` with whatever you have set up as the controller and action for your Ember app.

Comment: It should be in the Readme! Thanks for your help.