# Ember-cli-rails routing close to a classic rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-cli, ember-cli-rails

I have a classic rails app with haml and api part (`exemple.com/api/v1/`). I'm working on an ember app with [ember-cli-rails](https://github.com/rwz/ember-cli-rails) that I want to be accessible at `/front` for the moment.

The problem is when I'm reloading it fails. The app go back to haml page or fail to route me correctly.

I checked [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32168466/ember-cli-rails-no-route-match-for-embers-paths) and try to implement it without success.

My routes.rb have nearly 400 lines. But for the moment the only thing who works is to add on the top of the file

```
  namespace :front do
    get '/', to: 'front#index'
  end
```

When I'm going on `exemple.com/front` is ok. If I click on `user list` I jump to a page at `exemple.com/stores/5282/users` when I click on a specific user `exemple.com/stores/5282/users/345`. When I reload

```
No route matches [GET] "/stores/5282/users"
```

To avoid failing I added this:

```
  match 'stores/*path', to: redirect('/front'), via: :all
```

But it just go back to the index page on my ember app. I've try also

```
  get 'stores/:all', to: "front#index"
```

But again no route matches.

**EDIT** : I've found an answer

```
  get 'stores/*other', to: "front/front#index"
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is :

```
 namespace :front do
    get '/', to: 'front#index'
 end

 get 'stores/*other', to: 'front/front#index'
```

Now when I go to `exemple.com/stores/5282/users` and I refresh it goes on the correct ember page. No route errror, no rediriction to `/front`.

Comment: Please, provide explanation for your code snippet, why and how it solves the problem.

Comment: @GwynBleidD is it better ?